# create a folder by given name through Inputbox

Tags: vbscript

I have found this script to create a folder but I would like to create a folder with naming through InputBox.

**Step 1:** When I hit the VBscript file, the inputbox will pop up.

**Step 2:** After popping up, I need to give the location with folder name where I need create a folder

Please let me know if this possible.

```
Dim oFSO
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Create a new folder
oFSO.CreateFolder **"C:\MyFolder"**

' Copy a file into the new folder
' Note that the destination folder path must end with a path separator (\)
oFSO.CopyFile "\\server\folder\file.ext", "C:\MyFolder\"
```

Comment: `CreateFolder()` argument expects a string and `InputBox()` returns a string, so?

Comment: Another duplicate for the pile [Create a folder based on user input vbscript](//stackoverflow.com/a/22512149)

Comment: It works fine for me now, thank you!

Answer (score -5):

Something like this?

```
folder=InputBox("Please enter the folder name","Folder")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oFSO.CreateFolder folder
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works but when I prefer the location it keeps failing to create folders. I can create a folder when this script is placed.

Comment: @SaravananShanmugam You will need to put the full path in, not sure if that's what you've been doing, but an example would be putting in `C:\test`, otherwise it will create in the folder the script is in.